# What is this horizontal point & confidence graph called?

Tags: r, data-visualization, descriptive-statistics

From page 166 of the [Open Intro to Stats](http://www.openintro.org/stat/down/OpenIntroStatSecond.pdf), what is this type of graph called? It represents 25 point estimates of a mean, together with their confidence intervals, centered around the actual population mean. The red line is a point estimate whose 95% confidence interval fails to capture the true population mean.

Further, is there a default R command to plot these graphs? Most graphs in the book seem to have been generated with R...

[image: line graph]

Comment: I think this is a Forest plot. See [Forest plots using R and ggplot2](http://statbandit.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/forest-plots-using-r-and-ggplot2/)

Comment: Cleveland dot plot (with confidence intervals).  Preferable to sort by effect size.

Comment: It depends on the community. For instance, Excel calls it a "high-low-close" plot because such things are used to chart prices of assets in markets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a Forest plot. See [Forest plots using R and ggplot2](http://statbandit.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/forest-plots-using-r-and-ggplot2/)

Comment: This is most definitely a forest plot: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_plot  They are most commonly used in meta analysis to compare estimates from different studies.